# Slack API: how do I format a slack message so that the user id is formatted as the user name?

Tags: slack-api

How do I post a message via the Slack API using the Slack user id (for example `U123456789`) but have Slack display the message as a link to the user (for example `@bobby`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show a username with link the syntax is:

```
<@{userid}[|{text}]>
```

Examples:

- `<@U12345678>` will display @bob with a link to bob's profile.
- `<@U12345678|This is Bob>` Will display "This is Bob" as link to his
  profile.

Note that using this user links also automatically creates a notification for the mentioned user.

Check [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users) for the official documentation.